# How do I check for dependencies before installing a Slackware package?

Tags: slackware, dependencies

I have a question with regard to dependency checking.

Before I download a package, I need to check to see if I have some of the dependencies already installed. How do I do that? I don't want to spend time downloading something I already have.

Comment: Hi Terence! Questions should be reasonably scoped, which means: One question at a time, please. Feel free to ask another question about your second issue, but consider including more info, maybe about the versions of programs you're using, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most Slackware packages depends on already installed packages (tagged as required and installed by default) or are self-contained. This is regarding the official Slackware packages, packages from third parties may require additional software to run (however, most authors include in their release notes what extra software you may need or even include it with the package).

In summary, there is no way to do it with pkgtool, most of the time is not necessary, and you should read the release notes if you are using third-party packages.

Installing from source is another matter, but in that case, you may end up compiling also the dependencies, so read the release notes.

After years of using Slackware servers, the only dependency hell I've found was when installing Perl software, until I started using the CPAN shell, which will install the modules you want along with their dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Slackware has a `slackpkg` utility, which is useful for that. So, if you know the package's name(*), which is a dependence, you can exec --as root-- `slackpkg search packagename`; also you can looking for specified files with: `slackpkg file-search packagename`.

(*)When you compile a Slackware package, you download first the source code from sites (like slackbuilds.org, slacky.eu), in that sites, you can see the dependencies for each package. Then the compile process begins, and finally you install the package using `installpkg` utility

Alternatively, you can use an utility like `slapt get` (http://software.jaos.org/) which is an utility that allow install third part slackware packages resolving dependences.